# command line processing outside of main in c

Tags: c, command

I am having a problem with processing command line arguments outside of main.  My code is supposed to do basic math operations when the user enter two numbers at the command line.

e.g. "Program name" -add 1 2
output: 3

The only function allowed in the main function is the function to process the command line argument and then do basic addition.  I am getting errors when trying to call the arguments.  Here's my code....

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    void process(int args, char *argv[]);  //Used to process arguments from the command line.
    int add(int num1, int num2);
    int main()
    {
         process(args, *argv[]);
         return (0);
    }
    void process(int args, char *argv[])
    {
        int i;
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < args; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[i], "-a") == 0 || strcmp(argv[i], "-add") == 0) // Line to get -a or -add switch to add two numbers.
            {
                 add(num1, num2);  //add function call
                 printf("%d");  // print result
            }
        }
    }
    int add(int num1, num2)
    {
         return num1 + num2;
    }
```

The errors that I'm getting are that args and argv are undeclared.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this task with just using the process function?

Comment: `int main()` --> `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` and `process(args, *argv[]);` --> `process(arc, argv);`

Comment: `printf("%d");` will invoke *undefined behavior* for luck of arguments.

Comment: argv[n] and argv[n+1] are convert to int as `num1` and `num2` then  `printf("%d\n", add(num1, num2));`

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
     process(args, *argv[]);
     return (0);
}
```

Where do you think `args` (which should be `argc`, by convention) and `argv` come from?

Also, why did you include the `*` and `[]` when passing `argv` to `process()`? Try to actually *understand* the code you're writing instead of just copying/pasting pieces in and massaging them until things compile.

The definition of `main` doesn't have to include them, but your program requires them. So do this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     process(argc, argv);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a comment, not an answer for me.

Comment: @MikeCAT I was about 19 seconds too late getting the "answer" part in there.